# JAVA hmac-sha256 library error

Tags: java, eclipse, hex, base64, sha256

I need a function that hmac-sha256 encodes 2 strings. I found this block of code but my eclipse compiler keeps saying "Hex cannot be resolved".

```
public static String encode(String key, String data) throws Exception {
      Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
      sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

      return Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
```

I also tried this: and got the error "Base64 cannot be resolved".

```
  public static String encode(String key, String data) throws Exception {
      Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
      sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

      return Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
```

My imports are:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Object;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

and i'm using JRE System Library(JavaSE-1.7).
My question is how do I fix those error codes?

Comment: Java 1.7 is out of support. Use 1.8 to write secure code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) in your class path and fix your `import` statements to include the right classes from it.

Comment: PS it's the first hit when I put `encodeHexString` into my internet search engine.